# Change image when pressed react native

Tags: react-native

I currently have the black and white images of zodiac signs and when I click on these I managed to get the color images of the zodiac signs. The thing is that the state doesn't change until I press it again. And I want to only show the actual sign that is clicked. How can I do it ? Here is my code where I manage the change of image :

```
        state = {
            belier:false,
            balance:false,
            cancer:false,
            capricorne:false,
            gemeaux:false,
            lion:false,
            poissons:false,
            sagittaire:false,
            scorpion:false,
            taureau:false,
            verseau:false,
            vierge:false
          }

          render() {
            return (
              <View style = {{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent:'space-between', position:'relative'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setState({belier: !this.state.belier});{this.showBelier()}}}>
                  <Image style = {styles.image} source={ this.state.belier === true ? require("../Images/couleurs/icons8-belier-100.png")
                : require("../Images/gris/beliergris.png")}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
)}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, at the top of your file require both of your images.

```
const image_one = require("../Images/couleurs/icons8-belier-100.png");
const image_two = require("../Images/gris/beliergris.png");
```

Then you can render it in multiple ways. For example, through a function:

```
someFunc() {
  if(this.state.belier) {
    return (
      <Image style={styles.image} source={image_one} />
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <Image style={styles.image} source={image_two} />
    )
  }
}

// Then in your render function

render() {
  return (
    <View>
    {this.someFunc()}
    </View>
  )
}
```

You can also render it inline using conditional rendering like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={() => this.setState({belier: !this.state.belier})}>
        { this.state.belier &&
         <Image style={styles.image} source={image_one} />
        }
        { !this.state.belier &&
         <Image style={styles.image} source={image_two} />
        }
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yeah this let me change one image to an other but I have 12 images in black and white, and I want to only change one to a color one whenever it's clicked. And when I will click to the next one, it will now display this one in color and the other one will be in black and white again. It's this part that I can't manage to do

Comment: Have you tried [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over the images, in which you can return a toggle-able image?

Comment: No I haven't tried map. So I need to make an array of my images ?

Comment: Is it correct ? I'm a new developer so it's not immediate for me